# How to copy a file to common desktop (how to address common desktop) with Group Policy?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, desktop, user-profile, copying

Using Group Policy Object > **User** > Preferences > Windows Settings > Files I can copy a file to user desktop using a target file name like this: `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\targetfile.txt`.

Now I'm trying to do similar task, using Group Policy > **Computer** > Preferences > Windows Settings > File.

What *shortcut* should I use instead `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\` to do it right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct environmental variable is `%DesktopDir%` for the current user, and `%CommonDesktopDir%` for all users. Group policy environmental variables are different than the standard environmental variables. You can see a list of all of them by pressing <kbd>F3</kbd> in any text field:

[image: Group Policy Environmental Variable Dialog Box]

Comment: Great tip. That's I was looking for. What a shame that F3 key isn't indicated anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

There is common desktop that you can use to populate files, shortcuts, etc for all users. Change your target to C:\Users\Public\Desktop.

Unfortunately, the only all userprofile variable is %allusersprofile% in my environment it points to c:\programdata which is not useful.

Comment: OK, this should be safe for standard installation of Windows 7/8/10. All of them have got C:\Users\Public\Desktop. And maybe it's enough for 99% of cases.

Comment: Please mark as answer to help others find there is a solution.

Comment: You could also use `Item Level Targeting` to prevent those other 1% cases. You might also look at `%public%\Desktop`